# How to restrict "type=number" to certain decimal places

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am developing an application in which i require to restrict the amount "type=number" filed to certain (2 places) places. Below is the HTML rules for element :
Please can someone help me regarding this query, Thanks in advance :

```html
 <input type="number" name="amount" ng-model="orderStock.amount" class="form-control" id="amount"
                        step="0.01" min="10" max="9999.99" placeholder=" Please enter Amount" ng-disabled="isDisabled"
                        required />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach an **input** event listener to your input element and check if it's value contains a comma. If it does, check if there are more than two characters to the right of the comma and remove the excess.

```js
function process() {
  var text = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var index = text.indexOf(".");
  if (index > -1) {
    if (text.length - index > 3) {
      document.getElementById("amount").value = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("input", process);
```

```html
<input type="number" name="amount" ng-model="orderStock.amount" class="form-control" id="amount" step="0.01" min="10" max="9999.99" placeholder=" Please enter Amount" ng-disabled="isDisabled" required />
```

If you want to have all the code inside the html tag, you can do this:

```html
<input type="number" name="amount" ng-model="orderStock.amount" class="form-control" id="amount" step="0.01" min="10" max="9999.99" oninput="var text = this.value;var index = text.indexOf('.');if (index > -1) {if (text.length - index > 3) {this.value = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);}}" placeholder=" Please enter Amount" ng-disabled="isDisabled" required />
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply...Could be stop directly on HTML page using some pattern?

Comment: You could probably put the oninput handler directly into the `<input>` tag - if that's what you mean. Otherwise there's no property that would limit the number of decimalplaces.

Comment: I refined my answer to include an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I applied "pattern="^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$" on the input tag along with the "step=0.01". And now its working as expected. Thanks for giving an approach.

Comment: Aaah, that's what you mean by pattern. I wasn't aware of this possibility. Good solution!

Comment: But however there is problem with the value 12.0000000000000000 insertion as its not restricting it to 2 decimal places? Can you suggest to restrict this value also to 12.00 as above step along with pattern is not working for this case